# Having trouble getting the output to print to the right decimal after second level of if statement

Tags: java, netbeans, printf, decimal

I am working a project for a loan calculator. The goal is to vary the interest rate based on the customers credit score. The if(finalScore <=550) works fine and prints the monthlyPayment to 2 decimal places like I want. The problem I have ran into is when I go to the next if statement "if(finalScore >550 && finalScore <=680)" It will print the monthly payment incorrectly. The output looks something like 147.04938.19 just as an example.

I tried changing the %.2f in my printf to %.2d and it corrects the issue but throws an illegal format exception.

Any advice here?

```
         if(finalScore <= 550) {}
        if (mortgage.equals(mlType)){}
            if (lYears == 30) {


                double interestRate =  mIR550[0]/100 + pRate;


                double monthlyRate = interestRate / 12.0;

                int termInMonths = 360;
                double monthlyPayments = ((mlAmount*monthlyRate)
                        /(1-Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -termInMonths)));
                System.out.printf("%.2f", monthlyPayments); 
    //prints fine here in format xxx.xx
```

Example of correct output:

```
    Please enter Credit Score: 
    550
    Loan Type Mortgage: 
    Mortgage
    Enter Years: 
    30
    Enter Loan Amount: 
    20000

    ___________________________________
    147.03
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 minutes 24 seconds)
```

Example of bad output

```
    Please enter Credit Score: 
    680
    Loan Type Mortgage: 
    Mortgage
    Enter Years: 
    30
    Enter Loan Amount: 
    20000
    ___________________________________
    147.03125.10
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 30 seconds)
```

Code where problem is occuring

```
    if(finalScore >550 && finalScore <=680) {
        if (mortgage.equals(mlType)){
            if (lYears == 30) {


                double interestRate =  mIR680[0]/100 + pRate;


                double monthlyRate = interestRate / 12.0;

                int termInMonths = 360;
                double monthlyPayments = ((mlAmount*monthlyRate)
                        /(1-Math.pow(1+monthlyRate, -termInMonths)));
                System.out.printf("%.2f", monthlyPayments);
                // output returns answer formatted xxx.xxxxx.xx not sure 
                   why?
```

Comment: can you put just the necessary of your code, or you can provide a small and clear example that describe your problem please?

Comment: I attempted to clean it up a bit. Problem I am having is the output. For the first block of code it gives me the correct output in format xxx.xx but when I run the last block of code I get an output in format xxx.xxxxx.xx

Answer (score 1):

You have two if-then-else-if chains; hence probably two times a System.out.printf.

The reason for this is the closing brace at:

```
    if (finalScore <= 550) {
    }
```

You probably meant to enclose the first if-chain.

And then the printf did not print a line break, so when printing say 1.23 and 4.56 one prints 1.234.56. A newline goes as follows:

```
        System.out.printf("%.2f%n", monthlyPayments);
```

Your IDE probably has a Format command, which should help.

Comment: add a System.out.println(); after that line of code.